# Insert data from one table to another table using Symfony

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

For this question I found few answers on Stack overflow but those questions didn't help my problem.I'm using symfony2 framework.

I want to insert data from one table to another and delete data in the first table.

Let's say there are two tables called Book & Author.
(note that Author table has additional table fields)

```
  public function BooktoAuthorAction(Request $request, $id) {

    $response = new Response();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $books = $em->getRepository("BooksBundle:Books")->findBy(array('booktype' => 'novel'));

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();    
    $query = $em->createQuery(
                    'INSERT INTO contact(bookName, isbn)
                     VALUES('book_name', 'isbn_no')
                         );   
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

      $em->flush();
   }

    return $response;
}
```

I have a table field called 'book_type' where i store which category particular book belongs to.I want change the book type,for example when inserting data from Book table to Author table i want to change the book_type **'novel' to 'drama'**

Also i want to delete data row from Book table once data transferred to Author table.

*note that I changed the variable names Method names of the real code.

**UPDATE**

I found the solution for my problem.I have updated the code.I'm now passing the data from Book table to Author table using entities instead of queries.

*Author and Books are two different Entities in two different Bundles

```
public function BookAuthorAction(Request $request, $id) {

    $response = new Response();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $books = $em->getRepository('BooksBundleBundle:Books')->find($id);
    $author = new Author();

    $author->setBookName($books->getBookName());
    $author->setIsbnNo($books->getIsbnNo());

    $author->setBookType('drama'); //passing a string as a book type

    $em->persist($author);
    $em->remove($books);
    $em->flush();

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: Why don't you simply run a couple of queries in MySQL instead?

Comment: I can't i'm working on a project.Where form details get submitted to tables using Actions methods

Comment: I see, you still can use it trough your functions (I guess)...

`INSERT INTO table1 (field1, field2, booktype, field n) SELECT field1, field2, 'drama', fieldn from table2 WHERE author='xxx' and booktype = 'novel'` then `DELETE from table2 WHERE author='xxx' and booktype = 'novel'`

Wouldn't be interessant to one book being able to fit in more than one category though?

It could be both a Novel and a Drama for instance?

Comment: I tried your code. query is getting submitted without any errors,unfortunately data is not passing to the second table.
$query = $em->createQuery(
                        'INSERT INTO author(first_name, last_name)
                         SELECT (first_name ,last_name) FROM books
                             ');   
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
as i told you these are not real variable names, the project i'm working on is a Sales Force App. I didn't try your last query yet. I need to fix the data passing issue.I'll try again

Comment: symfony is using entities. why do you use queries?

Answer (score 0):

Try Mapping your tables and updating accordingly;
[This](http://www.theodo.fr/blog/2013/11/dynamic-mapping-in-doctrine-and-symfony-how-to-extend-entities/) might help